# How to get Packet Processing(packet_in, flow_match, output) time in OVS switch?

Tags: sdn, mininet, openvswitch, ryu

I'm trying to evaluate a routing technique implemented by me with Mininet, Open vSwitch and Ryu controller. But currently I'm unable to figure out the measurement techniques of packet processing time within switch. I can measure probe message processing time as `packet_in` occurs for those and reports back to controller program. But how to measure processing time for packets whose presence will not be reported back to the controller by switch(`packet_in` will not occur)? Probably `ovs-ofctl` command has some options that can report me the time. But still not sure how to do that. Please help me in this circumstance. I have not got enough resources over the internet. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by `packet processing time within switch`? Do you mean the time it takes Open vSwitch as a whole (datapath + slowpath) to process a packet? Do you want to measure this for each packet, or as an average?

Comment: Thanks @pchaigno I want to measure for each packet. And I'm interested to get the time between packet_in and packet_out.

Comment: So that's the processing time at the controller? Why not measure it at the controller (either in the controller itself or by tracing at the operating system level)?

Comment: The packets I'm going to send will not contact controller as there is matching rule in the Open vSwitch flow table. @pchaigno do you know how to measure the delay inside each OVS. or any command that can log the packet entry and exit time? Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: The PACKET_IN message will not reach the controller?? I'm not sure I follow you anymore...

Comment: No packet_in message will reach to controller only if no flow match to the table. But for my case flow will match the table entries. So no message will go to the controller. Its something about Open vSwitch. There might be some log I guess which tracks the packets. But thanks @pchaigno for your help so far.

Comment: Oh, so you mean you have a PACKET_IN message going through a second switch that matches it? It would help if you could detail your setup (switch(es) and flow tables).

Comment: I have done proactive setup of flow tables( all forwarding rules are added initially). As there is matching rule in flow table of a switch so packet that enters to that switch interface will be matched to the flow table. As match results in a output port, packet will exit through that port. As there is no flow match miss (as packet matches the rules inside flow table) there will be no controller communication. So no packet_in event will be triggered and controller will not know anything about that packet. thanks @pchaigno for your query.

Comment: Then, why did you say "And I'm interested to get the time between packet_in and packet_out."?? So, you want the time between the reception of the packet by Open vSwitch and its transmission (or drop) on the network card?

Comment: yes. sorry about the confusion @pchaigno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using the **kernel datapath of Open vSwitch**, you should be able to retrieve the processing delay for each packet using the usual **Linux tracing** toolkits.

Below is an example using the BPF infrastructure (requires Linux v4.4+) and [the bcc toolkit](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc) (I have version 0.5.0-1). Note, however, that for high packet rates, the overhead from running this tool may be significant. Another way to measure the overhead your modifications add is to measure the maximum throughput the switch can achieve with and without your modifications.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bcc import BPF
import sys
import ctypes as ct

prog = """
#include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>
#include <linux/openvswitch.h>

struct vport;

enum action_t {
    DROP = 0,
    OUTPUT,
};

struct proc_record_t {
    u64 delay;
    enum action_t action;
};

BPF_HASH(pkts, struct sk_buff *, u64, 1024);
BPF_PERF_OUTPUT(events);

// Take a timestamp at packet reception by Open vSwitch.
int
kprobe__ovs_vport_receive(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct vport *port, struct sk_buff *skb) {
    u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
    pkts.update(&skb, &ts);
    return 0;
}

// Once the packet has been processed by the switch, measure the processing delay and send to userspace using perf_submit.
static inline void
end_processing(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sk_buff *skb, enum action_t action) {
    u64 *tsp = pkts.lookup(&skb);
    if (tsp) {
        u64 ts = bpf_ktime_get_ns();
        struct proc_record_t record = {};
        record.delay = ts - *tsp;
        record.action = action;
        events.perf_submit(ctx, &record, sizeof(record));
        pkts.delete(&skb);
    }
}

// Called when packets are dropped by Open vSwitch.
int
kprobe__consume_skb(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct sk_buff *skb) {
    end_processing(ctx, skb, DROP);
    return 0;
}

// Called when packets are outputted by Open vSwitch.
int
kprobe__ovs_vport_send(struct pt_regs *ctx, struct vport *vport, struct sk_buff *skb) {
    end_processing(ctx, skb, OUTPUT);
    return 0;
}
"""

b = BPF(text=prog)

class Data(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("delay", ct.c_ulonglong),
                ("action", ct.c_int)]
actions = ["drop", "output"]

print("%-18s %s" % ("DELAY(ns)", "ACTION"))

# Callback function to display information from kernel
def print_event(cpu, data, size):
    event = ct.cast(data, ct.POINTER(Data)).contents
    print("%-18d %s" % (event.delay, actions[event.action]))

b["events"].open_perf_buffer(print_event)
while True:
    b.kprobe_poll()
```

You'll need to [install bcc](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md) to execute this script. Then, it's as simple as:

```
$ sudo python trace_processing_time.py
DELAY(ns)          ACTION
97385              drop
55630              drop
38768              drop
61113              drop
10382              output
14795              output
```

See [the bcc documentation](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial_bcc_python_developer.md) for details on how this script works. You will need to change it if you want to support more OpenFlow actions (only `drop` and `output` currently).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'll do further some modification of your program. But thanks a lot for your valuable time.